# react prop-types: custom validators not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

In the official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes), it is stated that one can specify a custom validator for type checking.

---

My custom implementation of a validator below does however never execute and I cannot figure out why that is.

In the following example, `funcWithArgs` should be used to validate a function based on the # of its arguments, as for instance an "onClick" function here takes 1 single arg. However, `funcWithArgs` never executes.

```
const funcWithArgs = argCount => (props, propName, componentName) => {
  var func = props[propName];
  if (typeof func !== 'function' || func.length !== argCount) {
    return new Error(
      `${propName} must be a function with ${argCount} number arguments`,
    );
  }
};


Component.propTypes = {
  onClick: funcWithArgs(1)
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`funcWithArgs` is executing. It's returning an error, which isn't being handled. Replacing `return new Error` with `console.log` prints the `propName` message in a browser console, demonstrating that the function is being called.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gracious-mountain-ff6ix)

Answer (score 1):

I originally thought that it was because you hadn't marked your parameter as required, but I found that it was executing for me in any case.

But as a learning exercise, I reimplemented it to support .isRequired too!
Pardon the typescript...

```
function funcWithArgs(argCount: number) {
    function impl(this: any, props: any, propName: any, _componentName: any) {
        const func = props[propName];

        if (this?.isRequired || func !== undefined) {
            if (typeof func !== 'function' || func.length !== argCount) {
                return new Error(
                    `${propName} must be a function with ${argCount} number arguments`,
                );
            }
        }
    }

    impl.isRequired = impl.bind({ isRequired: true })
    return impl;
}

Component.proptypes = {
    onClick: funcWithArgs(1).isRequired
}
```

Comment: Thanks to https://twitter.com/anatomic for the inspiration here:
https://www.ian-thomas.net/custom-proptype-validation-with-react/